# Jquery changing ID of cloned element children not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone an element and then change the id of one of its children:

```
var s = $('.RunWell').clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
s.find('#tag' + runNum).attr('id', 'tag'+ (++runNum));
```

but it is not working, what am I doing wrong ??
how to change the ID of a child of a cloned element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to go to its html..just use the cloned jquery object.

try this

```
var s = $('.RunWell').clone().wrap('<div>');
s.find('#tag' + runNum).attr('id', 'tag'+ (++runNum));
```

Comment: ok, can you tell me what is wrong with this code ??

var s = $('#runwell1').clone().wrap('<div>');
               
                s.find('#tag' + runNum).attr('id', 'tag' + (++runNum));

                
                $('#addrun').before(s.parent().html());

Comment: try this  `$('#addrun').before(s)`

Comment: I will try... but will take some time.

Comment: I added the html code in this question,please check it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232462/jquery-cant-clone-an-element-using-its-id

Comment: added my answer .. please check

Comment: Hey @bipen please check this question with my full code and try to answer it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275570/twitter-bootstrap-input-tags-not-working-with-jquery-before/19275875?noredirect=1#19275875

Answer (score 2):

the line

```
var s = $('.RunWell').clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

assigns variable `s` with a string value. But you are assuming it to be a jquery object in the next line by performing a [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on it.

It should be

```
var $s = $('.RunWell').clone().wrap('<div>').parent();
$s.find('#tag' + runNum).attr('id', 'tag'+ (++runNum));
//$s is used to denote it as a jquery object to provide more readability to code.
```