# jquery can't clone an element using its id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone a **div** using Jquery,then change one of its children's id and the add after another element:

```
var s = $('#runwell1').clone().wrap('<div>');
s.find('#tag' + runNum).attr('id', 'tag' + (++runNum));
$('#addrun').before(s.parent().html());
```

but this code is not working. what is wrong with it ?? how to clone using id ??

**edit** here is the html of the div:

```
<div class="well well-large RunWell" id="#runwell1">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Run 1</legend>

    <!-- Multiple Radios -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="radios">System :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="radio" for="radios-0">
                <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-0" value="op" checked="checked">
                OPE
            </label>
            <label class="radio" for="radios-1">
                <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radios-1" value="mxwl">
                Maxwell
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="textarea">Tools :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="tags" id="tag1" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing" data-role="tagsinput" />
        </div>
        </br>
        <div class="SystemFiles" data-role="collapsible">
            <!-- File Button -->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="filebutton">OP  DLIS </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" class="input-file" type="file">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What about this is not working?

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/6UeP3/).

Comment: "jQuery can't clone an element using its id" yes, yes it can.

Comment: Run a debug to see of runNum matches the tag's id and other stuffs...

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating your issue?

Comment: While I don't know why you would use `.before(s.parent().html())` instead of just `.before(s)`, your code doesn't look like it wouldn't work We need more context in order to assist you. Also note that after running this code, you'll have two elements on the page with the same ID, which can be problematic.

Comment: @jackwanders Not sure why the `.html` but `parent` is because `s` is wrapped in a `div` on the first line.

Comment: please check the edit, I added my html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have `#` in your id..

```
id="#runwell1" <---here

<div class="well well-large RunWell" id="#runwell1">
                          //-------------^----here
```

remove that `#` in the tag

and your id selector will work..

Comment: Good catch! missed that +1

Comment: you saved my life twice today =) its not completely working but now I can handle it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need also to change the div of the `.clone()`, to avoid double IDs

Try this:

```
var runNum = 1;
var s = $('#runwell' + runNum)
    .clone()
    .attr('id', '#runwell' + (++runNum))
    .wrap('<div>');

s.find('#tag' + runNum).attr('id', 'tag' + (++runNum));
$('#addrun').before(s);
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8z9CK/1/)**

Comment: @AhmedKato, check bipen's answer and then try the code again. AND use my id suggestion so it's not double

Comment: actually it's working for the first time only !! and not working after that

Comment: @AhmedKato, did you use my code? I wrote about changing the id.

Comment: What is the other id? do you have #runwell1,2,3,etc ?

Comment: no, only one runwell1 and when adding another one will be runwell2, actually I used a an alert to debug,and runNum is incremented but the div is not added

Comment: @AhmedKato, like you see in my Fiddle, this code adds a new div runwell2 before runwell1.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = $('#runwell1').clone().wrap('<div>');
```

`s` will refer to what was in the selector WHEN IT WAS RUN. It will not contain what content has been manipulated in the DOM.